# Custom BindAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

Is there a way to implement your own BindAttribute. Preferably by deriving from BindAttribute, but if you need to impliment it in your own ModelBinder how would you go about doing this?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to archive?, most of the common problems can be solved with the default model Binder (except for some security checking)

Comment: I'm trying to get certain fields to only bind given certain user rights. One of the more commonly suggested routes is to have separate views and action methods for admin and non-admin editing but rather than doubling my code I'd rather be able to do something like
[AuthBind(Role="Admin", Include=..., Exclude=...)]
[AuthBind(Role="Person", Include=..., Exclude=...)]